# How can i get two values of status_code , message_error when i call procedure?

Tags: singlestore

In my procedure has a:

```
Return query : RETURNS query(`status_code` int(11) NULL, `message_error` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL
```

How can i get two values of status_code , message_error when i call procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `khanhnguyendevelop`.`test`(

        customerId bigint(11) NULL, 
        restaurantId bigint(11) NULL)
        RETURNS query(`status_code` int(11) NULL, `message_error` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL
)
DEFINER = 'root'@'%' AS
DECLARE 
    q QUERY(status_code INT(11), message_error VARCHAR(255)) =  SELECT  0, 'Success';
    `point ` BIGINT(20) =  0;
    accumulatePoint BIGINT(20) = 0;
    promotionPoint BIGINT(20) = 0;
    aloPoint BIGINT(20) = 0; 

BEGIN   
    
    SELECT  IFNULL(cb.amount,0) AS point, 
            IFNULL(SUM(cmc.accumulate_point),0) AS accumulate_point, 
            SUM((IFNULL(cmc.total_promotion_point,0) - IFNULL(used_promotion_point,0) ))  AS promotion_point
    INTO   `point `,
            accumulatePoint,
            promotionPoint 
    FROM    customer_membership_cards AS cmc
            LEFT JOIN customer_balances cb ON cmc.customer_id = cb.customer_id 
    WHERE   cmc.customer_id = customerId 
            AND ((restaurantId> 0 AND cmc.restaurant_id = restaurantId) OR restaurantId < 0); 

   
    SELECT  SUM(IFNULL(cb.total_alo_point,0) - IFNULL(cb.used_alo_point,0))  AS alo_point
    INTO    aloPoint 
    FROM    customer_balances AS cb
    WHERE   cb.customer_id  = customerId;

    ECHO SELECT  customerId AS customer_id,
            restaurantId AS restaurant_id,
             `point `  AS point, 
            accumulatePoint AS accumulate_point,
             IFNULL(promotionPoint,0) AS promotion_point,
             IFNULL(aloPoint,0) AS value;
    
    RETURN q ;
END;
```

when call procedure just get :

[image]

Can anyone explain :((

See the value when on the screen